# IF AND CONCATENATE Nested Statement in Calculated Column SharePoint 2010

Tags: excel

I am having trouble nesting concatenate formula with if statement - syntax error. I am trying to create a calculated column. This column will list "master file" string if exist. If two master files exists (two separate columns), then this column should list both.
Example - master file 1 or None if none exist.
Master file 1, masterfile 2 if both exist. Below is my code so far. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
=IF([Master File]="[Choose Masterfile]","NONE LISTED",[Master File],IF(AND[Master File 2] <> '[Choose Masterfile]",CONCATENATE([Master File] + [Master File 2])))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND([Master File]="[Choose Masterfile]",[Master File 2]="[Choose Masterfile]"),"NONE LISTED",IF([Master File]="[Choose Masterfile]",[Master File 2],IF([Master File 2]="[Choose Masterfile]",[Master File],CONCATENATE([Master File], [Master File 2]))))
```

Something like this should work though you need to check the values are correct.

Comment: I used this code under. It still does do the concatenation. The good news is, it doesn't throw any errors: 'code=IF(AND([Master File]="[Choose Masterfile]",[Master File 2]="[Choose Masterfile]"),"NONE LISTED",IF([Master File]<>"[Choose Masterfile]",[Master File],IF([Master File 2]<>"[Choose Masterfile]",CONCATENATE([Master File],[Master File 2]))))'