# Conditional formatting in SharePoint Workflow Email

Tags: workflow, email, conditional

I have an issue where I have several check boxes (yes/no) on a form that my users fill out. Once they submit the form, it fires off a workflow to request work be done by the IT department. In the lower section there are a few Yes/No choices that are simple check marks on the form. Is there a way to **only** include the ones marked ***Yes*** in the email?

The current email format Looks like this:

> This is an automated email from the User Creation / Modification Workflow
>   Please create the following user in Active Directory with the listed permissions >and access rights indicated below:
>
> ---
>
> ***User Information***
>
> *First Name : [%Current Item:First Name%]*
>
> *Middle Name : [%Current Item:Middle Name%]*
>
> *Last Name : [%Current Item:Last Name%]*
>
> *Phone : [%Current Item:Phone%]*
>
> *Email : [%Current Item:Email Address%]*
>
> ***Access Levels***
>
> *VPN : Yes / No Choice*
>
> *SharePoint : Yes / No Choice*
>
> *Personal Folder : Yes / No Choice*
>
> *DMS : Yes / No Choice*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Jordan has suggested, another possibility is to put all the values in a choice field (check boxes) and call the field Access Levels.  Embed that field in the workflow email.  The end result will look something like below and will exclude any values not checked.  I did have to change the embedded value to comma delimited instead of string to get the workflow to fire.

Access needed: SharePoint,VPN

Comment: This is a much cleaner way to do it compared to the second part of my answer, which is the same end result that you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do it the way you are asking.

A workaround that you could do would be to make a calculated field that checks your four fields and whichever ones are checked **Yes** add it to your calculated field string.

With that you can place that field in your email and it will always show whatever is checked **Yes**.  It may be a bit more difficult to format it the way you have in the question, but functionally it should work the same.

EDIT:

If you wanted to simplify the calculated fields you could do something like this instead.

Create a calculated field for each of your Access fields (VPN, SharePoint, etc.) and give them a value like `=IF(VPN,"VPN: Yes","")`.  Then place those fields in your email.

The only downside with this would be the formatting would be off in the email the way you have it now, if say only VPN and DMS were **Yes**.  You would have blank string in your email and would like awkward.  If you can figure out a cleaner way to format that, perhaps keeping them on the same line that approach would be easier to set up the calculation.

Comment: Thanks. Ill give that a try and see what I can come up with. I know(assume) the logic is there ... just getting my brain to see it is the hard part.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction as far as what the logic would be for the calculated column.  You have four fields rather than two to check so it will be a bit more complex, but still the same approach should work.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72863/if-and-concatenate-nested-statement-in-calculated-column-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Added a slightly different approach.

Comment: Can I assume that you are using Visual Studio to do these types of changes? I have only been using SharePoint Designer up to this point.

Comment: Nope, no VS.  Can create the calculated fields right in the SharePoint UI or in SP Designer like you are using.  It's the same as creating any other field type, you just select `Calculated` as the type and place the formula in the `Formula` box not too far under that.

As far as editing the workflow, that is only through Designer.  It seems like (based on your question info) you have a good grasp on how to set up the workflow and send the email which is all you should need to do.